# Using SCOPE_IDENTITY

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have simple code in Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio query window.

```
insert into [clients] ("Addres","companyID") values (NULL,NULL);
SCOPE_IDENTITY();
select  * from clients;
```

When I run it I have error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'SCOPE_IDENTITY'.

What is wrong? Without line  `SCOPE_IDENTITY();` everything goes fine.

Table clients:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[clients](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Addres] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [companyID] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use with select.

```
insert into [clients] ("Addres","companyID") values (NULL,NULL);
select SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```